# Input ignores IF statement if default in switch

Tags: java

I am doing a project (based on a tutorial). I have a switch statement and for each case, there's a default in case the user input is invalid, and I write on the console "Sorry, I do not understand your request". However, if the user instead of writing whatever, writes "exit", the program should end without that "I don't understand request" sentence showing up.

This is stated in my IF statement in the beginning. What my current project does at the moment when I type "exit" is showing that line and then stopping. I don't understand how the program completely ignores that IF statement in the beginning.

```
public class MainGame {

public static GameSave gameSave = new GameSave();
public static String user = "";
public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static String question;
public static int relationshipPoints;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        question = gameSave.loadGame();
        // relationshipPoints = gameSave.loadPoints();
        RelationshipPoints points = new RelationshipPoints();

        System.out.println("\n\t*** TEXT_GAME: FIRSTDATE ***\n");
        System.out.println("-You can exit the game at any time by typing 'exit'.-\n\n");

        while (true) {

            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            } else {
                switch (question) {
                [...]
                case "2":
                    switch (user = scanner.next()) {
                    case "1":
                        System.out.println("\n\nThe guy you met last night was nice. You want to "
                                + "get back into contact with him. Why don't you check your phone for a number?");
                        question = "2A";
                        gameSave.saveGame("2A");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("\n\n");
                        question = "0";
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("\nI do not understand your request.\n");
                        question = "2";
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "2A": [...]
```

Comment: please enhance that code to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try: `user.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("exit");` it could be that the newline character is what failing the comparison

Comment: @TimothyTruckle sorry I don't know how to do that, the code is huge, I can't copy paste it all!

Comment: @alfasin tried it but doesn't work, program still reaches System.out.println("\nI do not understand your request.\n"); then ends. I just want it to end without showing that line.

Comment: @Evan of course it will... you're reading the input in the "switch" and check it in the "if" only in the next iteration of the while loop...

Comment: do the user = scanner.next(); at the top of the while loop

Comment: @alfasin Yeah but switch is inside else. If the IF says program should end if input "exit" then shouldn't it just end? in any case, how can I fix this?

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy doesn't work :/

Comment: @alfasin sure it does. show an updated form of what you have.

Comment: it really doesn't. If I put user = scanner.nextLine(); above the while loop, program first waits until I type something, I do, then program begins as normal, and if at any moment I type "exit", it shows the line before ending. Line always appears. EDIT: sorry I meant @MeBigFatGuy

Comment: in the while loop, not above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user = scanner.nextLine();` insert this line just after entering in `while loop`. your problem occurs as you are checking `user` equal to `exit` but `user` has nothing so control goes to `else` portion.

Comment: sorry it doesn't seem to work. If I put user = scanner.nextLine(); above the while loop, program first waits until I type something, I do, then program begins as normal, and if at any moment I type "exit", it shows the line "I do not understand your request" before ending. Line always appears. :/

Comment: @Evan sorry just put that line below `while loop`.

Comment: Thanks @jack jay That works! Now program ends without showing that line.  However now my game's messed up, I need to input everything twice for the program to go onto the next question O.o

Comment: you can try this, remove `if condition` and inside each `first switch` cases you check whether `user = exit` and proceed your code accordingly. In this way you can get rid of giving twice inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `while(true) {...}` with `while ((user = scanner.next() != null) { ... }`

It looks like you are trying to access the "user" data without first setting it.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to write this but there's error "can't convert from String to boolean".